# How to reference nested stack resources in AWS cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am currently using Serverless framework .As the number of resources exceeded 200 limit I used serverless-nested-stack plugin to create nested stack .Since then resource from one nested stack  cannot  access resource from other stack.
How do I refer a resource from one nested stack from another nested stack ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why the metro bundler does not start on it's own. You have to be on the same network or there might be an issue with the adb. Can you please refer to this [webpage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) for more clarity on how to run the app on device. It helped me out a lot while having issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the react native cli , I uninstalled the react-native-cli and use 'npx react-native run-android' to run the app .This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this from your command prompt:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```